# achieve high speed video live streaming with low bandwidth network

Tags: networking, upload, udp, video-streaming, wowza

I am doing video live streaming using  wowza media server and vlc. my broadband maximum upload speed is 512kbps but i need to stream(upload) a video file
with 1mbps speed. i talked to the internet provider to increase upload speed they told me that they will provide upload speed maximum of 512kbps.

I searched internet for some solution but nothing helped

so made a theoretical solution by using two internet connection.

1. From the server side start udp streaming using vlc
2. By applying socket programming and multitasking take the udp packet
   send to two different network parallely.
3. From wowza side receive udp packets from two network parallely then arrange the udp packets properly then stream the video.
4. So i sending to two 512kbps network so that i can get 1mbps speed.

Image of my idea: 
[image]
is it good idea or not if not please tell me some solution to achieve this.

I think i may get negative vote for this question. i don't know whether this right place to ask this question, I didn't find the solution anywhere.

**EDIT:**

Wowza server installed in remote dedicated server.

I need to stream(upload) video to remote wowza server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your wowza server installed ? in your PC or on a remote dedicated server a high speed connection ? You have not provided more information.

I assume you have wowza in a different dedicated server with high speed, in that case, you will have to find some alternate means to have an 1Mbps connection if you are doing a live streaming, and you dont want to compromise the quality.

If its only ondemand you want only the viewers to see it in 1Mbps, then you can upload the videos even with 512kbps, it wouldnt make any difference.

Comment: Wowza server installed in remote dedicated server. I doing live streaming.